# Robotframework RIDE: text in Edit panel is not markable

Tags: python, wxpython, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Settings:

> - Windows 10. Python 2.7
> - different versions of RIDE: from 1.1 up to 1.5.2.1.
> - wxpython different versions from 2.8 up to latest.

When I double click any text in "Edit" panel and try to mark it by holding the left mouse key and moving mouse, nothing happens: the cursor does move but the color of text doesn't change.
In the 'text edit' panel everything's fine, any text can be selected/marked properly, the problem is only with the 'Edit' panel.

I have the same version of python, ride, wxpython on Windows 7 and text marking 
is normal there.

Has anybody encountered such problem? 
Maybe it's some kind of incompatibility with Windows 10?

Comment: Can you select text pressing "Shift" and arrow keys?

Comment: Yes, I can select just like Verv's described, I can copy paste it, but the selection itself is not visible (the color doesn't change)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue back when I was using RIDE. One thing you should know is, even though you don't actually see the text being selected, it is selected. In other words, if you do a CTRL+C, it will effectively copy the text you selected, you just don't visually see it being selected.

As for what causes this exactly, I'm not sure but I wouldn't bother searching too much either. RIDE really has a lot of annoying bugs like this one, and with last commit being 2 years ago, I'd say it's not maintained anymore.

You might wanna switch to raw test data editing (equivalent of text edit in RIDE) using a modern IDE like Pycharm or any other good IDE you like that offers Robot Framework test data editing, or perhaps you could try out [RED](https://github.com/nokia/RED), which is kind of an upgraded RIDE.

Comment: Thanks, but judging by the video this RED just doesn't feel as convinient as RIDE, plus I couldn't open it, as I keep getting some  strange expections like Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.

Comment: This might sound like a longshot, but I've kind of found an alternative way:
Windows 10 has ubuntu bash(unix) support, so I've installed wxpython,ride,robotframework and run it via xming server and it seems to work fine- text is selected/marked properly.